# Why does the integral equal $1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$. Why is the following equality true?

$$1 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \left| e^{-i(\pi-x)a} \right|^2 dx$$

More precisely, why is the integrand equals $1$?

Comment: **HINT:** $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$. Therefore $|e^{i\theta}|=\sqrt{\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)}=?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true for $a\in \mathbb Z$ too.

$-(\pi-x)a$ is real, so $-i(\pi-x)a$ is purely imaginary. It is well known that
$$ e^{it}=\cos t + i\sin t \qquad\qquad\text{when }t\in\mathbb R$$
so its modulus is $\sqrt{\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t} = \sqrt 1 = 1$.